# Why is Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL running multiple MySQL queries (not eager loading)?

Tags: laravel, graphql, eager-loading, laravel-lighthouse

I am new to GraphQL and Lighthouse.

My understanding from https://lighthouse-php.com/4.0/performance/n-plus-one.html#eager-loading-relationships is that for a nested GraphQL query, "Under the hood, Lighthouse will batch the relationship queries together in a single database query."

However, I see in the logs all of these queries where there should be only 1:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `posts`
select * from `posts` order by `created_at` asc limit 20 offset 0
select * from `post_files` where `post_files`.`post_id` in (249, 5...
select * from `post_tags` where `post_tags`.`post_id` in (249, 5...
select * from `comments` where `comments`.`post_id` in (249, 5...
select * from `files` where `files`.`id` in (269, 615, ...
select * from `tags` where `tags`.`id` in (2, 3, 4, ...
```

Here is my GraphQL query:

```
gql`
    query Posts($page: Int) {
        posts(
            first: 20
            page: $page,            
            orderBy: { field: CREATED_AT, order: ASC }
        ) {
            paginatorInfo {
                currentPage
                hasMorePages
                total
            }
            data {
                id
                content 
                created_at
                postFiles {
                    file {
                        id
                        original_name 
                        extension
                    }
                }
                postTags {
                    id
                    tag {
                        id
                        label 
                    }
                }
                comments {
                    id
                    user_id
                    message 
                    created_at
                    seen_at
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

My schema.graphql has the right `@belongsTo` and `@hasMany` directives:

```
"A date string with format `Y-m-d`, e.g. `2011-05-23`."
scalar Date @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\Date")

"A datetime string with format `Y-m-d H:i:s`, e.g. `2018-05-23 13:43:32`."
scalar DateTime
    @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\DateTime")

"A datetime and timezone string in ISO 8601 format `Y-m-dTH:i:sO`, e.g. `2020-04-20T13:53:12+02:00`."
scalar DateTimeTz
    @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\DateTimeTz")

type Comment {
    id: Int!
    user: User! @belongsTo
    user_id: Int!
    post: Post! @belongsTo
    post_id: Int!
    message: String!
    emailed_at: DateTime
    seen_at: DateTime
    created_at: DateTime!
    modified_at: DateTime!
}

type File {
    id: Int!
    original_name: String!
    extension: String!
    postFiles: [PostFile!]! @hasMany
}

type Post {
    id: Int!
    user: User! @belongsTo
    user_id: Int!
    content: String
    origin: String
    created_at: DateTime!
    modified_at: DateTime!
    postFiles: [PostFile!]! @hasMany
    comments: [Comment!]! @hasMany
    postTags: [PostTag!]! @hasMany
}

type PostFile {
    post: Post! @belongsTo
    post_id: Int!
    file: File! @belongsTo
    file_id: Int!
}

type PostTag {
    id: Int!
    post: Post! @belongsTo
    post_id: Int!
    tag: Tag! @belongsTo
    tag_id: Int!
    created_at: DateTime!
    modified_at: DateTime!
}

type Tag {
    id: Int!
    label: String!
    hash: String!
    created_at: DateTime!
    modified_at: DateTime!
    postTags: [PostTag!]! @hasMany
}

type User {
    id: Int!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    salt: String
    db_key: String
    created_at: DateTime!
    modified_at: DateTime!
    posts: [Post!]! @hasMany
    comments: [Comment!]! @hasMany
}

type Query {
    comments: [Comment!]! @all
    files: [File!]! @all    
    posts(
        orderBy: _ @orderBy(columns: ["id", "created_at"], order: ASC)
    ): [Post!]! @paginate(defaultCount: 20)
    post(id: ID! @eq): Post @find
    postFiles: [PostFile!]! @all
    postTags: [PostTag!]! @all
    tags: [Tag!]! @all
    users: [User!]! @all
}
```

My Laravel models have all the right relationships. E.g. class Post has:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, Comment::POST_ID);
}
```

And class Comment has:

```
 public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class); 
 }
```

and so on.

Comment: They are batched - each relation separately - ids `in` sets, not every id in separate query, not hundreds of queries .... Are you expecting this, batched queries to be joined, too? dreams ... These few queries should be good enough for most use cases ...  Are you really need all this data at once? really?

Comment: @xadm Am I misunderstanding that sentence from the documentation that says it turns into a single query? Currently mine is very slow, so yes, I was thinking it would help to convert to one query. Thanks.

Comment: single per subtype/relation ... IMHO joining all can change only a little ... test it ... check joined query execution time ... you don't need comments, tag labels can be read/cached earlier

Comment: @xadm I manually wrote a single join, and it selected 44,426 rows in 0.171 seconds. The Lighthouse separate joins summed to be even faster, somehow. So you are right that the DB query alone isn't the problem. The unwanted outcome is that Lighthouse takes 49-67 seconds to load the page (probably because it's costly to map all the nesting relations). I wonder if it could load faster if it used my single giant query. And yes, I do want to load ALL at once rather than use pagination. It ought to be possible. I don't know why GraphQL would make this harder than without GraphQL. Thanks!

Comment: In practice this is done much more sequentially - post ids, posts, "extraction" of related ids, related entities, matching related to posts ... there is always some cost (are you really want to display all comments or files on posts list?) ... probably there is a method to optimize this more in Lighthouse (some custom resolvers?), search within issues on github/open new issue?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Type hinting

import these types

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
```

And

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

public function post() : BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class); 
 }
```